# Wait until PDF page is loaded with Selenium WebDriver for Python

Tags: python, selenium, pdf

I want to print something like "Page is ready" when the PDF page has loaded.
Example page: [example page](https://readthedocs.org/projects/selenium-python/downloads/pdf/latest/).
I try to explore page to show back-end code and do wait until some element is located, but it is not working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Test():

    def __init__(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("drivers\chromedriver.exe")
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://readthedocs.org/projects/selenium-python/downloads/pdf/latest/")
        self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "icon")))
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("icon").click()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    oTest = Test()
```

**Could Someone help me?**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you expect an icon to exist in a pdf file?

Comment: Just a quick take, but your .presence_of_element_located call has two enclosing parenthesis. Is this necessary?

Comment: @rangeseeker yes, it is important

Comment: When I inspect menu icon (top-left corner) I can see the code: `<div id="icon"><div id="maskedImage"></div><iron-icon></iron-icon></div>`